# User program failed with ValueError: ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Running pipeline failed with the following error.

`User program failed with ValueError: ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980`

I created Azure ML Pipeline that call several child run. See the attached codes.

```py
# start parent Run
run = Run.get_context()
workspace = run.experiment.workspace

from azureml.core import Workspace, Environment

runconfig = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory=".", script="simple-for-bug-check.py")
runconfig.run_config.target = "cpu-cluster"

# Submit the run
for i in range(10):
    print("child run ...")
    run.submit_child(runconfig)
```

It seems timestamp of python script (simple-for-bug-check.py) is invalid. 
My Python SDK version is 1.0.83.

Any workaround on this ?

Regards,
Keita

Comment: can you please share the "simple-for-bug-check.py".

Answer (score 1):

One workaround to the issue is setting the `source_directory_data_store` to a datastore pointing to a file share. Every workspace comes with a datastore pointing to a file share by default, so you can change the parent run submission code to:

```py
# workspacefilestore is the datastore that is created with every workspace that points to a file share
run_config.source_directory_data_store = 'workspacefilestore'
```

if you are using RunConfiguration or if you are using an estimator, you can do the following:

```py
datastore = Datastore(workspace, 'workspacefilestore')
est = Estimator(..., source_directory_data_store=datastore, ...)
```

The cause of the issue is the current working directory in a run is a blobfuse mounted directory, and in the current (1.2.4) as well as prior versions of blobfuse, the last modified date of every directory is set to the Unix epoch (1970/01/01). By changing the `source_directory_data_store` to a file share, this will change the current working directory to a cifs mounted file share, which will have the correct last modified time for directories and thus will not have this issue.